# Simulink setting signal to zero for specified time period when an increase is detected

Tags: matlab, simulink

I am trying to model get my input signal to zero for a set period (around 100 ms) when an increase is detected in another signal.

This is to model a motorbike quickshifter using simdriveline, although I am modelling this by cutting the throttle signal (In2) which is between 0 and 1 rather than the spark at the engine directly. The increase is the gear signal (going from 1 to 2 etc) in In1.

Please find the block diagram below:

[image]

I am having two problems. When I run this with no gear changes (No increase in In1) I don't get the proper output for some reason? and secondly I get the same problem if I do run it with a gear change. The model works fine if I bypass this block altogether.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do this simply with the Detect Increase block linked to a Monostable block with the required time set